# Why does Albia constantly change appearance?

Tags: girl-genius

In the webcomic *Girl Genius*, the queen of England, Albia, is a sort of "second-level Spark" who has achieved sufficient understanding that she no longer needs to build devices to mock the laws of physics (as do most Sparks) but can produce essentially magical effects directly. Part of this ability is that she is able to change her size and appearance, the latter of which she does constantly and seemingly almost unconsciously.

However, when we see other queens or queen-adjacent entities, such as the scientists and cultists who tried to emulate Albia's abilities, they automatically grow in size as their power increases, and might gain some features such as floating hair or glowing eyes, but do not drastically change their appearance on the spur of the moment. Further, when we see Albia when she is low on power, she seems to lapse into a state where she is completely bleached of color (not merely light-skinned), with completely white skin and dull gray hair.

Why does Albia's appearance constantly shift?

Comment: I just assumed that she's _always_ projecting an appearance that she feels suits the moment, and we just finally saw something like her actual appearance when she was totally drained (albeit probably less grey when she's not on the verge of collapsing).

Comment: @DavidW - That is one possibility, but my impression is that she seems to shapeshift almost unconsciously in line with her emotions. Also, if she does feel that her different appearances suit the moment, there's kind of a question of why.

Comment: @DavidW - To be honest, given her habit of solely referring to herself with the royal "we," her apparent status as a Spark formally specializing in mental science/magic, her seemingly being the last remaining queen, and the dubious relevance of (say) hair color or skin tone to expressing one's feelings, I kind of wonder whether she is actually a kind of composite entity of multiple queens, having taken their minds into herself in the aftermath of Lucrezia's attack and giving herself a sort of fantastical multiple-personality condition.

Comment: *shrug*  My guess is morphic resonance, projected self-image, or some other nonsense, combined with centuries experience.  I have nothing to back that up.  I doubt it's illusion though... there were lines early on to avoid that suggestion.

Comment: Because there are so many different ways to look fabulously regal? Because she wants to reflect the diversity of her citizenry? Because it is simply enjoyable? Because…

Comment: I think she's showing off her power, so people wouldn't question her. Looks like the comics is back on the road, after.... a whole year of filler? And were getting more insight into her.